# What's the mathematical symbol to say "It doesn't depend on ..."?

Tags: education

If I want to say x doesn't exist I would use the symbol $\nexists$
If I want to say x is a member of... I would use  $\in$

But what's the symbol to say  *y*  doesn't depend on *x*?

I know I could write something like  y$\neq$f(x)  but I'm looking for a single symbol, something more compact, without the  *f* northe parenthesis.
Does it exist?
In fact f(x) represents a function, and we could have a relationship without a function.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "depend on"?

Comment: Depending on what you mean, you could use $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$

Comment: Is it really necessary to have notation for this? (I'm not being snappish, I just am curious.) Do you need to say it dozens of times or something?

Comment: If there are three variables $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ that $y$ *could* depend on, you might write something like $y = y(x_1,x_2)$ to indicate that $y$ depends only on $x_1$ and $x_2$, but not on $x_3$. If $x$ is the only variable, you might write $y = \text{const}$ or something like that.

Comment: @William Stagner  Depend on means that if you modify the value of x then y also modifies its value. And if we were speaking about random variables it would mean that  the distribution of y is different for different values of x

Comment: What context is this writing in???  As a general rule I tend to assume variables are independent unless stated,  however this does depend on the author.

Comment: I just want to know it in general, if there exist such a symbol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, the notation already exists, and I have found it.

The book "Bayesian Reasoning and Machine Learning" provides a mathematical notation list, where it says:
[image]

Then, this pi-like symbol, and the reversed pi mean that a variable is dependent or independent on other variable.
I don't know if it's only used in a statistical framework or also in general in mathematics.

It's strange nobody knew it.

Comment: Not strange at all. My knowledge is micro-encyclopedic, and I never heard of this notation.

Comment: So, in this book it is "stochastic independence".    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)  I suppose there would be another symbol when we talk about "linear independence" another for "algebraic indepencence" and yet more for other sorts of independence.